# Use of NTILE with dynamic query result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below table with some test data

```
create table TestTable
(  
  torque number,
  torqueValues number
)

insert into TestTable values(1,10);
insert into TestTable values(1,20);
insert into TestTable values(1,30);
insert into TestTable values(2,1);
insert into TestTable values(3,2);
insert into TestTable values(5,10);
insert into TestTable values(9,1);
insert into TestTable values(9,12);
insert into TestTable values(10,15);
insert into TestTable values(10,10);
```

I am trying to apply NTILE in oracle and divide the record set into multiple groups.
When I am running below query its working fine.

```
select torque,NTILE(2) over(order by torque)  from TestTable
```

But when I am trying to pass dynamic values to NTILE, its throwing missing expression error. below is the query

```
select torque,
NTILE(  
  select count(*)/2 as countvalue from TestTable
over(order by torque)  from TestTable
```

Could you please point out where am i making mistake. The same query is   working fine SQL server but oracle it throws error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same query is working fine SQL server but oracle it throws error.

No, it gives error in SQL Server too : [**Check This**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/377b5/7)

Try this using a `with` clause in Oracle, it works.

```
WITH t
AS (
    SELECT count(*) / 2 AS countvalue
    FROM TestTable
    )
SELECT torque
    ,NTILE(countvalue) OVER (
        PARTITION BY countvalue ORDER BY torque
        ) as tile
FROM TestTable
CROSS JOIN t;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12d70/16)

An important point to note here is that `PARTITION BY countvalue` is required or else it will throw this error.

> ORA-30488 Description: argument should be a function of expressions
>   in PARTITION BY

I'm still not able to get a proper source for the above restriction from Oracle docs or anywhere else. As for  SQL Server, even this doesn't seem to work :[**Check this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/377b5/4)

Comment: Thanks for response. I am closing the request.